Why can't iscan (or xsane) see my Epson Perfection V350 (USB) on an Ubuntu 24.04 system?
I'm in need of a recipe for interfacing with my [favourite] scanner, an Epson Perfection V350 Photo.
I was previously using xsane and iscan on my ubuntu 18.04 machine with no trouble. On a new laptop on which I installed Ubu 24.04, neither xsane nor iscan find the [USB-connected] V350.
iscan installed successfully (after following the help in Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic -> Epson iscan > Unable to locate package libsane) but when I start it, it pops up a message box: Could not send command to scanner. Check the scanner's status. which makes me think there is some permission problem with the usb port.
lsusb finds the device: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04b8:012f Seiko Epson Corp. GT-F700 [Perfection V350]
sane-find-scanner finds: found possible USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x012f [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:001:002
scanimage -L only finds my one networked scanner, irrelevant to this issue
Over the last few days, I've downloaded and installed various packages:
https://download2.ebz.epson.net/iscan/general/deb/x64/iscan-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz
After downloading and installing libsane (libsane_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb) the previous iscan download installed, but doesn't find the USB-connected V350.
I went crazy and downloaded a couple of windows versions of TWAIN scan interfaces from Epson and installed them in wine bottles. Neither find the V350 (neither display any UI or error messages; they seem to quietly die.) I changed the permissions of the /dev/usb/001/002 from 664 (rw-rw-r- for root:root:other) but no one seems to talk to my V350.
Has anyone successfully installed xsane or iscan for a USB-connected scanner? Bonus points for an Epson Perfection device!

This question is similar to: USB 2.0 device (scanner) does not work with xhci_hcd on USB 3.0 system. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This worked for me today:
Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic -> Epson iscan > Unable to locate package libsane
(I had to restart after installing the drivers, then my scanner software recognised the scanner)

Thank you; I found that thread and it helped get around the "libsane not found" error, and iscan starts, but pops up "Could not send comand to scanner. Check the scanner's status." which leads me to think of a permissions problem. (I've restarted several times since getting libsane resolved.) I'll edit my question to clarify that.
